# Lucene Tokenised field starts with

Tags: lucene, index

I'm trying to replicate a lucene query of

```
+_name:mat* +_name:butl*
```

which works in Luke, but the Sitecore linq produces

```
+spanFirst(SpanWildcardQuery(_name:mat*), 1) 
+spanFirst(SpanWildcardQuery(_name:butl*), 1)
```

which returns 0 results. Any idea on how to produce a query that matches on the start of the tokens

Comment: Can you add an example of the code you are writing?